# IBM MobileFirst: Unable to read repositories

Tags: mobilefirst-studio

I have been trying to install IBM MobileFirst on Ubuntu 14 Eclipse Luna through the Eclpise market place. It always aborts at 44% with the error below.

Anyone knows what the problem could be and do I solve it.

Thanks.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_6.3.0.00-20150106-1717.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-builder_6.3.0.00-20150106-1717.jar.
Read timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more like a network issue than anything else.
Try installing the .zip locally.

You can download the .zip file from here:  http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip